# Getting OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Java

Tags: java

I am getting this below error upon running build.xml file running through ANT through Eclipse although I am passing additional vm arguments `-Xms512m -Xmx1524m`, but still I am getting out of heap space error. Please advise how to fix this.

```
compileEJBSource:
     [echo] compileEJBSource ...
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\AVN\FT\CoreERT\Product\classes
    [javac] The system is out of resources.
    [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
    [javac] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.getRawCharacters(Scanner.java:1075)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.DocCommentScanner.getLineMap(DocCommentScanner.java:417)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseCompilationUnit(JavacParser.java:2310)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.EndPosParser.parseCompilationUnit(EndPosParser.java:83)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:595)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.complete(JavaCompiler.java:741)
```

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? What's up with your user name?

Comment: try to print your vm arguments and see whether it is there.

Comment: Janath how we can print the same in build.xml do we need to echo in the build.xml file

Comment: How to overcome: 1) Increase heap size of Ant process, e.g. `-Xmx3g`, 2) Use `<javac fork="yes" memoryMaximumSize="3g">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9314551/1531971

Answer (score 0):

You could set it as an option for ANT. Use "ANT_OPTS"

`set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Please see [Increase memory for ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330540/increase-memory-for-ant)

Comment: where to set in eclipse please advise

Comment: Soryy, I do not have eclipse. Is there something like 'Environment-Settings' in the dialog?